# how to use "Select debug app" and "wait for debugger" new feature in jelly bean?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

"Select debug app" and "Wait for debugger" are new feature in Jelly Bean, does someone know how to use these new features?

Answer (score 22):

I found the answer here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html

> Lets you select the application to debug. You do not need to set this
>   to attach a debugger, but setting this value has two effects:
>
> - It will
>     prevent Android from throwing an error if you pause on a breakpoint
>     for a long time while debugging.
> - It will enable you to select the Wait
>     for Debugger option to pause application startup until your debugger
>     attaches (described next).

Answer (score 2):

It is a mystery to me also, but I'll share my experience.   I cannot see that these options change the phone's behavior.   Regardless of the settings I choose, the Galaxy Nexus behaves like my older phones that do not have the settings.

"Waiting for debugger" is a dialog that I see whenever I start running an app from Eclipse.  It stays up for a while, and then my app starts running.  This has been the case since I started Android development, and it still works that way on my old and new devices, regardless of the setting.

If I click on "Select Debug App", it allows me to select an app from the already installed apps on my phone that allow debugging, which are the apps that I wrote myself.

On my Galaxy Nexus it does not matter whether I select "Nothing" or one of my debuggable apps, I can still debug any app from Eclipse.   I cannot even see a difference in time it takes to load an app over the ADB connection.